MariaDb: Difference between login commands "sudo mysql" and "sudo mysql -u root -p"?
I am running an Ubuntu 22.04 LEMP Server.
I am trying to log into MariaDB and show a list of ALL of my databases. However, I get two different lists of databases, depending on how I log into MariaDB. I have run sudo mysql_secure_installation and changed to the unix socket authentication.
If I log into MariaDB using sudo mysql I get this (which lists only SOME of my Databases, not all of them):
sudo mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 14306
Server version: 10.11.9-MariaDB-ubu2204-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| Database1          |
| Database2          |
| Database3          |
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.002 sec)

If I log into MariaDB using sudo mysql -u root -p I get this (which lists ALL of my Databases):
sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 14330
Server version: 10.11.9-MariaDB-ubu2204-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| Database1          |
| Database2          |
| Database3          |
| Database4          |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| Database7          |
| performance_schema |
| Database9          |
| Database10         |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
11 rows in set (0.002 sec)

Im wondering why these MariaDB Login methods yield different results of the show databases; command, and what the meaning of each command is (i.e. Are my permissions set correctly?, Does this imply different ownership of databases and how so?, What is the meaning of each way to log in in terms of security? Why do both logins require no password, but just the push of the enter key? etc.)
Any relevant information and explanation would be much appreciated!

sudo is nothing to do with Mariadb. You are using different authentication mechanisms - and hence different permissions are applied. Check the content of the mysql.user and mysql.database tables.

"Check the content of the mysql.user and mysql.database tables." @symcbean How exactly do I do that?

Sounds like you have a default user; see the config file.  And that user does not have all permissions.  On the other hand, the database's root (as opposed to the OS's "root") has all permissions, so it see all the tasks running.
sudo is a 'red herring'.  It is unnecessary in this context.
